# "Cannot convert to IComparer"

Tags: c#, icomparer

I have the following IComparer defined for boxed RegistryItem objects:

```
public class BoxedRegistryItemComparer : IComparer<object>
{
    public int Compare(object left, object right)
    {
        RegistryItem leftReg = (RegistryItem)left;
        RegistryItem rightReg = (RegistryItem)right;

        return string.Compare(leftReg.Name, rightReg.Name);
    }
}
```

I want to use this to sort an ArrayList of boxed RegistryItems (It really should be a List`<RegistryItem`>, but that's out of my control).

```
ArrayList regItems = new ArrayList();
// fill up the list ...
BoxedRegistryItemComparer comparer = new BoxedRegistryItemComparer();
ArrayList.sort(comparer);
```

However, the last line gives the compiler error:  "Cannot convert from BoxedRegistryItemComparer to System.Collections.IComparer".  I would appreciate it if someone could point out my mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`BoxedRegistryItemComparer` should implement `System.Collections.IComparer` to be used with `ArrayList.Sort`. you implemented `System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<T>` which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

You've defined a [Generic-Comparer (`IComparer<T>`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) instead of a [Comparer without a type (`IComparer`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx). [`ArrayList.Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa317787%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) expects a non-generic `IComparer`.

Generic-Types can not be casted into their non-generic equivalents.

Answer (score 4):

In case you have a situation where you don't have any control over the Comparer or the Sorter, here are two mini-classes which can convert between the two types (untested):

```
private class GenericComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    IComparer _Comparer;
    public GenericComparer(IComparer comparer)
    {
        _Comparer = comparer;
    }
    public int Compare(T a, T b)
    {
        return _Comparer.Compare(a, b);
    }
}

private class NonGenericComparer<T> : IComparer
{
    IComparer<T> _Comparer;
    public NonGenericComparer(IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        _Comparer = comparer;
    }
    public int Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        return _Comparer.Compare((T)a, (T)b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is a crutch, but it works:

```
            arrayList.Sort(Comparer<object>.Create(
            (x, y) => ((RegistryItem)x).Name.CompareTo(((RegistryItem)y).Name)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BoxedRegistryItemComparer : IComparer {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to above post would be to have your comparer class implement both interfaces, then you can cast IComparer<T> to IComparer should you need both.

```
public class MyComparer<T> : IComparer<T>, IComparer
```