# PriorityQueue in C# doesn't work with custom comparer

Tags: c#, priority-queue, icomparer

Can someone help me understand why this doesn't work and how can make it work?

```cs
PriorityQueue<Candidate, int> pq = 
   new PriorityQueue<Candidate, int>(new EstimateCompare());
    
public class EstimateCompare: IComparer<Candidate>
{
    public int Compare(Candidate a, Candidate b)
    {
        int diff = a.estimateDistance -b.estimateDistance;
        return diff == 0 ? 0 : diff < 0 ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get:

> CS0535: 'EstimateCompare' does not implement interface member
> 'IComparer.Compare(int, int)' (in Solution.cs)

Tried using it like this and I get this error:

```
PriorityQueue<Candidate, int> pq = 
                    new PriorityQueue<Candidate, int>(new EstimateCompare());

public class EstimateCompare: IComparer<Candidate> {
      public int Compare(Candidate a, Candidate b) {
         return a.estimateDistance.CompareTo(b.estimateDistance);
     }
```

> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'EstimateCompare' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer?'
>
> ```
> public class Candidate {
>     int row;
>     int col;
>     int distanceSoFar;
>     public int estimateDistance;
>     
>     public Candidate(int row, int col, int distanceSoFar, int estimateDistance) {
>         this.row = row;
>         this.col = col;
>         this.distanceSoFar = distanceSoFar;
>         this.estimateDistance = estimateDistance;
>     }
> }
> ```

Many Thanks!!

Comment: From the docs: "We recommend that you derive from the Comparer<T> class instead of implementing the IComparer<T> interface, because the Comparer<T> class provides an explicit interface implementation of the IComparer.Compare method and the Default property that gets the default comparer for the object."

Comment: Can you show it by an example?

Comment: Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1?view=net-6.0. It has sample code where it repeats the warning to derive from Comparer, not IComparer. I don't know if that will solve your problem, but it's worth trying first.

Comment: This also seems relevant to your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487193/cannot-convert-to-icomparer

Comment: Thanks for sharing these two links. I have seen both of them before. I have a similar example that works for Sort but now it is not working for PriorityQueue. I am missing something here, have reviewed these two links and tried different combinations

Comment: I was following this https://code-maze.com/csharp-priority-queue/ and not sure why it does not work for me

Comment: Can you share your code for the Candidate class?

Answer (score 2):

The constructor you're using is [`PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>(IComparer<TPriority>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-priorityqueue-2-ctor(system-collections-generic-icomparer((-1)))), that is, `TElement` is `Candidate`, and `TPriority` is `int`, so the argument should be an instance of `IComparer<int>`, but `EstimateCompare` is an `IComparer<Candidate>`.

So for example, the example compiles if you instead used

```cs
PriorityQueue<Candidate, Candidate> pq = 
    new PriorityQueue<Candidate, Candidate>(new EstimateCompare());
```

But given what your implementation of `Compare` looks like, you probably don't want an `IComparer` at all, and you could instead do with your `PriorityQueue<Candidate, int>` and just use, say

```cs
pq.Enqueue(candidate, candidate.estimateDistance)
```

when adding elements to the queue.